# Cheapest dissection of a grid polygon into rectangles with cost

Tags: ds.algorithms, cg.comp-geom, heuristics

My problem:

- Dissect a grid polygon into rectangles. (A *grid polygon* is a [rectilinear polygon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectilinear_polygon) all of whose vertices have integer coordinates.)
- The rectangles must be taken from a predefined set (which includes a 1×1 rectangle, so the dissection is always possible).
- Each rectangle has a cost which is not directly proportional to its size (a 2×3 rectangle may cost less 'per grid square covered' than a 1×1 rectangle).
- No gaps or overlaps are allowed.
- The optimal solution is the cheapest that covers the area.

My first thoughts were to work out the cheapest 'per square covered' rectangle and fit as many of those into the area as possible, but it seems that might perform poorly if it means filling a lot of spaces with small, expensive pieces.

I realise this is likely NP-hard, so I am probably looking for a heuristic rather than an algorithm. It seems in some ways similar to a bin-packing problem or a knapsack problem, but I can't see how to extend the solutions to these problems. I may just be lacking the right terminology, so if anyone could point me in the right direction to get started, I'd be grateful.

Comment: Your solutions sounds like the simplest way to do it. It follows the standard greedy solution pattern - sort, then start going from best to worst. Try just sorting the rectangle list by efficiency (cost / space covered) and going from there.

Comment: It's normal to use the terms *dissection* when overlaps are forbidden (as in this case) and *cover* when overlaps are allowed. I changed the title accordingly.

Comment: If the set of rectangles were unconstrained, and every rectangle had the same cost, then [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6634668/68063) would explain how to compute the cheapest dissection.

Comment: Consider simulated annealing for this.

Comment: I'm considering experimenting with this using simulated annealing.  Do you have any sample data, and an appropriate cost function?

Comment: Sorry Deep, at this stage I've just been using random rectilinear polygons and assigning each rectangle size a random cost. Thanks for the tip though, I'll look into simulated annealing

Comment: @Kallikantzaros: This question could get good answers if it is asked on the new Computer Science SE site http://cs.stackexchange.com/. Can you try?